# ets:i/1 tty's second option meaning

Tags: erlang

I am now trying to study the internal ets structure of gproc project. When using the "ets:i/1" command, the tty gives me 3 options. What's the meaning of the (p)Digits?

```
(emacs@yus-iMac.local)35> ets:i(gproc).
<1   > {{<0.77.0>,l}}
<2   > {{<0.77.0>,{c,l,c1}},[{initial,3}]}
<3   > {{<0.77.0>,{n,l,{dummy,1}}},[]}
<4   > {{<0.77.0>,{p,l,prop}},[]}
<5   > {{{c,l,c1},<0.77.0>},<0.77.0>,3}
<6   > {{{n,l,{dummy,1}},n},<0.77.0>,undefined}
<7   > {{{p,l,prop},<0.77.0>},<0.77.0>,undefined}
EOT  (q)uit (p)Digits (k)ill /Regexp -->p
Bad digits
EOT  (q)uit (p)Digits (k)ill /Regexp -->1
EOT  (q)uit (p)Digits (k)ill /Regexp --><1>
EOT  (q)uit (p)Digits (k)ill /Regexp -->k
ok
(emacs@yus-iMac.local)36> ets:i(gproc).

=ERROR REPORT==== 7-Mar-2012::07:20:00 ===
** Generic server gproc terminating 
** Last message in was {'DOWN',#Ref<0.0.0.178>,process,<0.77.0>,normal}
** When Server state == {state}
** Reason for termination == 
** {badarg,[{ets,member,[gproc,{<0.77.0>,l}],[]},
            {gproc,process_is_down,1,[{file,"src/gproc.erl"},{line,1777}]},
            {gproc,handle_info,2,[{file,"src/gproc.erl"},{line,1689}]},
            {gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,597}]},
            {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,227}]}]}
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  ets:first/1
        called as ets:first(gproc)
     in call from ets:i/3 (ets.erl, line 1203)
(emacs@yus-iMac.local)37>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pNNN will print record number NNN.

for example:

```
(emacs@yus-iMac.local)35> ets:i(gproc).
<1   > {{<0.77.0>,l}}
<2   > {{<0.77.0>,{c,l,c1}},[{initial,3}]}
<3   > {{<0.77.0>,{n,l,{dummy,1}}},[]}
<4   > {{<0.77.0>,{p,l,prop}},[]}
<5   > {{{c,l,c1},<0.77.0>},<0.77.0>,3}
<6   > {{{n,l,{dummy,1}},n},<0.77.0>,undefined}
<7   > {{{p,l,prop},<0.77.0>},<0.77.0>,undefined}
EOT  (q)uit (p)Digits (k)ill /Regexp -->p3
{{<0.77.0>,{n,l,{dummy,1}}},[]}
```